# Call td child of tbody to set classname

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, I want to an getElementById for HTML tbody - A table body, and dynamically add class names to all td in the tbody. How do I do this?

Comment: Kindly check the answers given to such basic questions on stack overflow before asking your question.

Comment: I have at least 20 tabs open. I can't find one that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following-

1. give some id to html elements: `<tbody id='someid'>` `<td id='td1'`>
2. in JavaScript access these elements like below:

   `var tbody = getElementById('someid')` OR `$('#someid')`

To dynamically add class, you can do:

```
`$('#td1').addClass('yourclassname');`
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you very much